# How to authenticate a Firebase user with ChatSDK?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, chat, chatsdk

I've integrated Firebase into my app. I can authenticate with Firebase via email/password. Then I initialize the [ChatSDK](https://chatsdk.co/) and call `InterfaceManager.shared().a.startLoginActivity(this,true);` From there, the app is "taken over" by the default chat user interface and the functionality works great and `ChatSDK.currentUser()` returns the expected `User` object.

I would like to do the same thing with my own UI. To authenticate a user after ChatSDK initialization, I've tried:
`ChatSDK.auth().authenticateWithCachedToken();`
`ChatSDK.auth().authenticate(AccountDetails.signUp(email,pwd));`
`ChatSDK.auth().authenticate(AccountDetails.username(email,pwd));`

It is my understanding that I wouldn't be able to do `ChatSDK.thread().createThread(...)` until I have a valid `User`. However, after each authentication attempt, `ChatSDK.currentUser()` is `null`.

Looking at the ChatSDK [source code](https://github.com/chat-sdk/chat-sdk-android/blob/ee0dd085559e9a140db76015aff41172ed40ff37/chat-sdk-ui/src/main/java/co/chatsdk/ui/login/LoginActivity.java) and [documentation](https://github.com/chat-sdk/docs#code-examples), it appears this is the mechanism for authentication. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Subscribe is necessary, even if you aren't using it.

```
        ChatSDK.auth()
            .authenticateWithCachedToken()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    Log.d("Success","We're in!");
                }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        Log.d("Err",throwable.toString());
                    }
                });
```

Also, here's some code to start a new chat thread with a known user id.

```
    UserWrapper userWrapper = UserWrapper.initWithEntityId(firebaseUser.uid);
    userWrapper.metaOn();
    userWrapper.onlineOn();
    User otherUser = userWrapper.getModel();

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pd.show();

    ChatSDK.thread().createThread("", otherUser, ChatSDK.currentUser())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doFinally(() -> {
                pd.dismiss();
            })
            .subscribe(thread -> {
                ChatSDK.ui().startChatActivityForID(getApplicationContext(), thread.getEntityID());
            }, throwable -> {
                ToastHelper.show(getApplicationContext(), throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
            });
```